# get a userID of a facebook user with http request C# WPF

Tags: c#, facebook, httprequest

I'm trying to get the userID of a Facebook user, I already have the access_token and I use http request to do it. My simple problem is that : I want the user's id but my program just crash... I use WPF, C# Here is my little call :

```
var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + token + "&response_type=id");

        var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string postData = "'access_token='" + token;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        var stream = req.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        aTextBox.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will want to use TextReader to get the text from the response stream or use a library like RestSharp to make the call and do all of this work for you.

Comment: BTW, be sure to leave `access_token` in only one place `GET` or `POST`. Using `POST` method to retrieve data from Graph API pass `method=get` to indicate that you need data retrieval and not update.

Comment: well I'll check that, but for now my real problem is that 'WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();' doesn't work...

Comment: well I can't say anything because my program just crash... :S I have tried many ways to make it work but it doesn't...I tried with POST GET neither works...I have also tried différents kind of syntax but it still crash...someone has any idea why? I don't :(

Comment: @HugoCardin What is the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Web Browser for this! You may use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) for that kind of things:

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + token + "&response_type=id";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

string responseData = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```